# How to change js variables using buttons in the html page and have them be changed the next time the webpage opens?

Tags: javascript

I am making a parental control webpage that lets the parent allow certain websites to be visited and blocks some others. The parent should be able to set what websites to allow. But how do i make this and have the program allow those same websites the next time it starts without the parent having to hard code which websites to allow?

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Baboola Web</title>
    
    <style>


input{
    background-color: #1e3e5f;
    color:darkgrey;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:17px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), inset  2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border:none;
    padding-left: 5pt;
}
h1{
    color: aliceblue;
}
    </style>
    
    </head>
     <body style = "background-color:#356da6; font-family: sans-serif;">
           <h1>Baboola Web</h1>

           <form id = "form1">

             <input style = "width:1000px;" id = "url" placeholder="URL here. For allowed websites that start with http:// please type in the FULL URL, like http://www.example.com.">

             
           </form>

        <script>
            var rst = true;

            var f1 = document.getElementById("form1");
            var url = document.getElementById("url");

            f1.addEventListener("submit", function(e){

                e.preventDefault(); return false;
            })

            url.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                 

                
                   var d;
                    if(url.value[0]!="h" && url.value[1]!="t" && url.value[2]!="t" && url.value[3]!="p") {
                    d = "https://www." + url.value;
                    } else{
                        d = url.value;
                    }

                    if(d !="https://www.w3schools.com" && d!= "https://www.connexus.com"&&d!="https://www.wcf.artofliving.org" && d!="https://www.zoom.us"&&d.slice(-3, -1)!='ed' && rst == true){
                        window.location.href="file:///C:/Users/mihie/OneDrive/Documents/Coding2023/rstr.htm"


                    } else{window.location.href = d}
                

            });

        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Of course you could change stuff in that if statement that is there already

```
if(d !="https://www.w3schools.com" && d!= "https://www.connexus.com"&&d!="https://www.wcf.artofliving.org" && d!="https://www.zoom.us"&&d.slice(-3, -1)!='ed' && rst == true)
```

But i dont want the parent to have to do that.

Comment: If you want something to be preserved when you close the page, save it in `localStorage`.

Comment: Hi barmar, could you please explain a little more on localstorage?

Comment: [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: localstorage didnt work. it just said err connection timed out.  ```

Comment: No network connection is involved in using local storage, so I don't think that's related. But without seeing your code it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Note that your PC web page won't be able to control what the user does in other windows/tabs.

Comment: This would have to be done as a browser extension. These have a slightly different API for saving data.

Comment: I figured it out, barmar. I got localstorage to work. Thanks, I just needed to not add www to the wesites.